# JMS point-to-point chat

Tags: java, jms

I'm trying to do a simple point-to-point chat, but after running the program I get an exception:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to get registry service for URL: tcp://localhost:8080/ [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Failed to create connection; nested exception is: 
    org.exolab.jms.net.connector.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost:8080]
    at org.exolab.jms.jndi.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:146)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:732)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208)
    at zad1.Receiver.<init>(Receiver.java:24)
    at zad1.Client.lambda$new$0(Client.java:61)
    ....
```

What could be the problem? I'm a complete beginner at this.

Here's my code:

```java
    private Context context;
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Session session;
    private MessageProducer sender;

    public Sender() {
        try {
            Hashtable<String, String> properties = new Hashtable<>();
            properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.exolab.jms.jndi.InitialContextFactory");
            properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://localhost:8080/");

            context = new InitialContext(properties);
            ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
            Topic topic = (Topic) context.lookup("topic1");

            connection = factory.createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            sender = session.createProducer(topic);
            connection.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void send(String message) {
        try {
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage();
            textMessage.setText(message);
            sender.send(textMessage);
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The message from the exception indicates what the problem is:

```
Failed to connect to localhost:8080
```

When you configure your JNDI lookup you specify:

```java
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "tcp://localhost:8080/");
```

However, the JNDI implementation can't establish a connection to `localhost:8080`. Please ensure that the URL is correct for your environment and/or that the JNDI server is actually running on port `8080` on `localhost`.

Lastly, it's worth noting that the stack-trace for the exception you shared does not match the source code you shared. The stack-trace came from the constructor of a class named `Receiver`, but the source code you shared is for a class named `Sender`.